# Website Bug in navigation bar

Tags: css

I tried to check the issue multiple times in the top navigation but whenever I hover a menu the drop down always disappear. Here is the website http://dev2.websiteblue.com/vuerealestate/index.html. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **`ul li a:hover+ul`** to **`ul li:hover a+ul`**

*this is your final code:*

```
ul li:hover a+ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    color: #9E0000;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working :), but if I may ask what exactly is the problem I think it is almost the same when putting the hover in a or in li tag.

Comment: @RonnieJavienJr. if this answer was helpful you might want to mark it as "Accepted Answer". it's a way to say *Thanks* here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Add Change `ul li a:hover+ul` to `ul li:hover ul`

Remove padding of `.ul_navigation`

change `display: inline` of `.navigation > ul > li` to `display: inline-block`

Add `display: block` to `.navigation ul li a`